# Size of TexLive Full Installation on Ubuntu

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I installed TexLive full on Ubuntu 16.04 through terminal and while it said that it was about to install approximately 3GB of software I ended up with 6GB. Is this normal? Why it didn't install what it said that it would?

Comment: 6G sounds about right for a full install (I seem to have 5.4G in my texlive 2016 cygwin setup)

Comment: It wasn't referring to download size?

Comment: `du -sh /usr/local/texlive/2016` on my x86_64 platform with Ubuntu 16.04 and TeXLive full says  `4.9G`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't know. I am referring to the number the terminal mentions just before you authorize the installation.

Comment: Those are download sizes. It normally tells you it is going to download X Mb which after installing will require an extra Y Mb on disk.

Comment: Thanks everyone I now understand what happened. If you believe that this is a useful question to others feel free to add an answer.